# Change on close of dropdown

Tags: jquery, json

I have a dropdown that is populated by reading from an external JSON file. All works great but I would like to be able to select a name on the list and on the event of it closing, display just the initials.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    vals = $.getJSON("data/stafflist.json", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(e) {
          $(".initials").append('<option value="' + e.initials + '">' + e.forename + ' ' + e.surname + '</option>')
        });
    });
});
```

**The JSON file content :**

```
[
    {
    "forename": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "initials": "JS"
    },
    {
    "forename": "Jane",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "initials": "JD"
    }
]
```

Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
$('.initial').change(function() {
    // Display selected value
     var $value = $('.initial option:selected').val();
     $(this).find('option[value="'+$value+'"]').text($value);
});
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. The version above logs to the console fine, but can't get it to change the name selected to its initials when it closes.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Once you changed the text then you wont be able to get it forename again.

Comment: Works great! Appreciate the help. As you said, once it changes you can't change it again. Would it be possible to reset it back to before the your line of code runs should it be clicked again?

Comment: For that you have reload the code to populate it once again

Comment: Otherwise you have to store it forename in cache before changing it text, then you can reuse it.

Comment: If it is working for you please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As your content is dynamically loaded, here how to do it:

```
$(document).on('change', '.initial', function(){
    // this is the value of the selected option
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: logs to the console great, but say I select John Smith, rather than the dropdown now reading John Smith when it closes, how would I get it to display JS? Fairly new to this so still learning...